# Integrate GIT and ANT

Tags: git, ant

My requirement is pretty vast here. I need to integrate GIT and ANT such that using ANT, I will pull the latest commit to GIT and create a directory and copy the changed files to that directory.

I need to do all these actions in a single ANT Command. Could anyone please suggest me how can I do this.

Any suggestions much appreciated. :)

Comment: Any specific reason to use only Ant?

Comment: Hi Saurabh,Actually my project uses Ant tool to deploy. So only ant.... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "exec" task of Ant

```
<exec executable="git">
    <arg line="clone $GIT_URL" />
</exec>
```

This is very basic example of executing git commands from ant.
Coming back to your question,

> I need to do all these actions in a single ANT Command

Since you want to do a git pull and copy only the changed files into a new directory, this itself is not feasible in a "Single ANT Command".
However, you can add up all the required commands as a git-executable inside a single ant target.

Also I will suggest you to post what you have tried as that helps others to answer or suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution on how to fix it. Using macro command of ANT to execute git and using diff-tree option in git to find the file differences.
I used ant-contrib library to use for loop to loop between the file differences and for each file differences, I used copy command to copy the files between src directory to target directory.

By this way I was able to each my above requirement.